# Rbind data frames with names in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of names for data.frames in R, for example

```
names <- c("D1", "D2", "D3")
```

How can I now use `rbind_all` to bind all data.frames that have names in `names`?
That is, how can I reference `D1` directly instead of the string `"D1"`?

Comment: `list_df <- mget(names)` ? or if you want all the data in one dataframe use `result <- do.call(rbind, list_df)`.

Comment: Or `bind_rows(mget(names))` from `dplyr`